# Parse php array to make insert statement

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have an array like this:

```
$datas = 
[
    'name_1'=>'John',
    'name_2' =>'Mickey',
    'settings_1' => 'Settings 1',
    'settings_2' => 'Settings 2'
]

foreach($datas as $data){
    //get items here...
}
```

How to pair or parse those items to make insert statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (name, settings)VALUES('John','Settings 1');
INSERT INTO table (name, settings)VALUES('Mickey','Settings 2');
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: anyway you can make this into an array of arrays so `$users = [['name'=>John, 'settings'=>'setting 1'], ['name'=>Mickey, 'settings'=>'setting 2']];` then you can just foreach loop over a create an insert for each array

Comment: yeah, my problem is how to make that array of arrays. Please check update above. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code could be usefull for creating array of arrays. Considering array keys will be name_x and settings_x

```
foreach($datas as $key=>$value){
    // explode each key of the array
    $keys = explode('_',$key);
    $name = 'name_'.$keys[1];
    $settings = 'settings_'.$keys[1];
    // to generate array
    $new_array[$keys[1]]=array('name'=>$datas[$name], 'settings'=>$datas[$settings]);

}
print_r($new_array);
```

Loop the $new_array for insert query.

Output :

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => John
            [settings] => Settings 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Mickey
            [settings] => Settings 2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$datas = 
[
    'name_1'=>'John',
    'name_2' =>'Mickey',
    'settings_1' => 'Settings 1',
    'settings_2' => 'Settings 2'
];

$results = [];

foreach($datas as $index=>$data){

  //create an array out of $index breaking it at the '_' 
  //so array will be $parts = [0=>'name', 1=>'1'];
  $parts = explode('_', $index);
  //'name_1'=>'John' = $results[1]['name'] = 'John';
  $results[$parts[1]][$parts[0]] = $data;


}
//batch insert new formed array
//INSERT INTO tbl_name (name, settings) VALUES $results;
```

Comment: Thanks, is this regardless if it's not in incremental? Might be name_2 becomes name_100?

Comment: try it now, now it breaks the key to determine everything

Answer (score 1):

Check this, you must do some intermediate steps. Comments on code!!

```
        $datas = 
        [
            'name_1'=>'John',
            'name_2' =>'Mickey',
            'settings_1' => 'Settings 1',
            'settings_2' => 'Settings 2'
        ];

        $data_final = [];    


        foreach($datas as $key=>$value){
              $keyX =  preg_replace('/^(.+)_(\d+)$/', '$1', $key);// get the "type" (name, setting)
              $keyY =  preg_replace('/^(.+)_(\d+)$/', '$2', $key);// get the "index" (_1, _2  without "_")

              $data_final[$keyY][$keyX] = $value; // put in result
        }

        // make queries
        $sql = [];
        foreach($data_final as $datas){

                $fields = implode(", ", array_keys($datas)); //implode the keys to sql fields
                $values = implode(", ", array_map(function($a){return "'$a'";}, array_values($datas)));//implode values to sql values adding ''. WARNING: This not escape values. Use escape string function on mysqli obj or PDO to the right escape
                $sql[] = "INSERT INTO table ($fields) VALUES ($values);"; // populate query

        }
        $sql = implode("\n", $sql); // implode with new line
        print_r($sql); //results
```

IMPORTANT:

- You must have the right syntax "field_number" to respect the procedure
- You can use even with one or more of two fields per record
- You can use any field name, always respecting the "field_number" syntax

**[DEMO HERE](http://rextester.com/PDPQ70628)**